# How to get a random real number in the half-open interval [0.0,1.0)?

Tags: random, intervals

As far as I understand, `RandomReal[]` is able to generate random numbers between 0.0 and 1.0 so thinking in Terms of an interval this means [0.0,1.0]. Now I want to exclude explicitly the value 1.0, meaning to have a half-open interval like: [0.0,1.0).

Is their an easy way to do that?

Comment: `RandomReal[{0,1-$MachineEpsilon}]`?

Comment: Ignoring the fact that we're working with Floating point numbers, you should know that this question doesn't make sense for Real numbers. The chance of getting 0 or 1 is 0.

Comment: It's not clear from what documentation I've read that you can even get 0 or 1 from RandomReal, but if you want to ensure that you don't get them, then use rejection sampling. Something like `myRand[] := With[{rnd=RandomReal[]}, If[rnd==1.,myRand[],rnd]]`

Answer (score -5):

One approach:

```
If[(a = RandomReal[]^{100}) == 1., 1-RandomReal[], a]
```

Comment: ...but not zero, since there are a finite number of machine precision numbers between 0 and 1.

Comment: myRand[] := With[{rnd=RandomReal[]}, If[rnd==1.,myRand[],rnd]]

Comment: tl;dr use rejection sampling via recursion. That's the easy, off the cuff, kind of solution.

Comment: It's also just problematic because returning 0 if you get 1 doubles the chances of getting 0 compared to other numbers, meaning it's no longer uniform and also it's not clear that RandomReal contains 0 or 1.

Comment: If `RandomReal[]` returned `0.99999999999999`, the test `0.99999999999999 == 1.` would return `True` because `Equal` uses a tolerance of 2 bits. But, there are many machine numbers between `0.99999999999999` and `1.`, so it should not be rejected.